# Remove First element of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Her s the below my JSON is nd I want to remove the first line of its items, like coming as:

```
data.items = {"username":"usr1","profile": "usr2", "items":[{"s": "1","f": "usr2","m": "hey ebteween how u doing","fr":"usr1"}]}
```

**Update #1**

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        data.items.item.shift();
   }
```

want ito be like this

```
{"username":"usr1","profile": "usr2", "items":[]}
```

I am trying using the `data.items.slice(1)` method but somehow it is not working:

**Update #2:**

i tried the code by adding the `shift()` but in console i received:

console.log(data.items);data.items.shift();

```
[Object { s="1", f="usr1", m="m", more...}]
```

but actually it did not removed the element from the json object

Comment: if this is the jason string you may perhaps use this regex. try http://regex101.com/r/mA1uE2/2

Answer (score 3):

to delete an element, you could use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
// it'll delete the first element of the json
delete data.items[0];
```

if you want to delete a specify key, you have to use key name:

```
// delete the username key:
delete data.items["username"];
```

in your case you could just set again your key in this way:

```
data.items["items"] = [];
```

you have set your key with an empty array

Comment: arh.. which language is this? can you provide any reference..?

Comment: Well... it is JavaScript in deed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1):

First, `items` is a property of `data.items`, so to get it, you must access `data.items.items`
Second, it is not [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you want to use, but [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```
var data = {};
data.items = {"username":"usr1","profile": "usr2", "items":[{"s": "1","f": "usr2","m": "hey ebteween how u doing","fr":"usr1"}]};

data.items.items.shift();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is giving me an error: TypeError: `data.items.items is undefined
 

data.items.items.shift();`. I update my question again

Comment: Surely, you are not using the code I gave : http://jsbin.com/lomomonoluju/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: in console, i tried this: console.log(data.items);     data.items.shift(); : Update in Question

Comment: Please pay attention to what I write, and also to what **you** write :
`$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        data.items.item.shift();
   }`
What are you trying to do with that ?
`data.items` is not an array, but an object, which contains a property named `items` and **not** `item` which contains the array you want to use `shift()` on.