# How to Fix Multi Object Problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i am getting a json object and a json array or objects in one response i want to remove the object and leave the json array how can i do that?

i tried Slice Replace and filter but no success

`{"error":"no data"}[{"name":"Ali"},{"name":"Momin"}]`

to

`[{"name":"Ali"},{"name":"Momin"}]`

i just want to remove the first part of the response. the data is stored in `response.data` variable how to remove this?
i want to remove the error object from the beginning of the response how can i do that?

Comment: Is that really the raw response you are getting? That's not even valid json.

Comment: yes i just want to remove the first object and the other is valid

Comment: If its valid json, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25804047/10932741) if its not, you can convert that string to json, or split it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending/Parsing multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209527/sending-parsing-multiple-json-objects)

Comment: `'[' + response.split('}[')[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it always does that automatically you jusr need to put the variable as array and it will push the data into it one by one